# Why is git clone --recursive cloning detached submodules

Tags: git

I've added some submodules to my git repo using the following *(note the -b switch)*:

```
git submodule add -b dev-master git@github.com:OurCompany/The_Submodule.git
```

and when cloning the module recursively with

```
git clone --recursive -b dev-master git@github.com:OurCompany/The_Repository.git
```

the submodules get cloned, but running

```
git branch
```

indicates that the submodule is in a detached state.

I can fix by checking out the submodule with

```
git checkout dev-master
```

but isn't there a way to clone recursively with the submodules checked out on the tracked **dev-master** branch I added in the **git submodule add** step, instead of giving me a detached branch?

Answer (score 0):

The parent project does not track the tags (i.e. `master` or `dev-master`). It only pins the sha1-ids of each submodule.

If you now want to have all submodules point to the current `master` (which might not be the one you expected), you can run:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout dev-master
```